# KafkaSpout(Storm) uncompression messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kafka-consumer-api

I am using KafkaSpout to consume messages from Kafka.

The messages are produced with `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`
With gzip compression `props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");`

How do i set the compression type in KafkaSpout to consume the uncompressed messages?

Comment: According to [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression), it might be handled for you automatically. Are you getting errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gzip compression is handled automatically. 
If it is a text file then you can directly read with an input stream or for XML files you parse it as regular files.

Property `props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip");` is not required.

If there are any errors, please post it.